# Problema en laravel " Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController]."

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Hola cree un controlador con

PHP artisan make:controller HomeController --resource
HomeController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {

    }

    /**
     * Show the form for creating a new resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function create()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function show($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function destroy($id)
    {
        //
    }
}
```

, ya tengo mi vista

entonces lo enturo en web.php

Route::get('home', 'HomeController')->name('home');

y me sale el error **" Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\HomeController].."**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al crear una ruta ya sea `GET` o `POST` en Laravel tú debes indicar a qué función debe dirigirse y no solo pasarle el controlador completo, que es lo que haces.

Al hacer:

> Route::get('home', 'HomeController')->name('home');

No especificas a que función dentro de HomeController apuntas, para solucionar esto lo cambias por lo siguiente:

```
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home.index');
```

En caso de que tengas una ruta tipo `POST` lo haces de similar forma. Ej:

```
Route::post('home', 'HomeController@store')->name('home.store');
```

En caso de que requieras utilizar todo el conjunto del CRUD. utilizas el resource que crea todas las rutas en un solo comando.

```
Route::resource('home', 'HomeController');
```

La lista de rutas creadas serían:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
* Method |   URI            |    Name      |    Action            |  
-------------------------------------------------------------------
| GET    | home             | home.index   |HomeController@index  |
| POST   | home             | home.store   |HomeController@store  |
| GET    | home/create      | home.create  |HomeController@create | 
| PUT    | home/{home}      | home.update  |HomeController@update |
| DELETE | home/{home}      | home.destroy |HomeController@destroy|
| GET    | home/{home}      | home.show    |HomeController@show   |
| GET    | home/{home}/edit | home.edit    |HomeController@edit   |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: gracias por detallar tu respuesta :D

Answer (score 2):

Te falta especificar la acción en la ruta que indica el método en el controlador al cual accederá dicha ruta:

```
Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: ciertamente! , gracias :D por cierto sabras como hacer para cargar una imagen a mi base de datos desde aca? y como tener como una previsualizacion de la imagen en la base de datos?

Comment: Eso es una pregunta totalmente distinta, te sugiero que formules una nueva. Acepta esta respuesta si te sirvió.

Answer (score 1):

ese parece que es un resource que creaste en laravel

la forma seria

`Route::resource('home', 'HomeController');`

Answer (score 0):

Solo te falta el metodo del controlador al que quieres hacer referencia, seria:

```
Route:get('home', 'HomeController@accion')->name('home');
```

la forma de utilizar esa route sin especificar una accion del controlador es implementando el metodo __invoke en el controlador.

Comment: buenas y si ya utilice eso y solo me aparece la ruta pero no entra al controlador nada solo se pone en blanco no registra como podria solucionarlo[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJYsg.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJYsg.png)